# How to re-use data from a previous post to be used in a new one with ASP .NET MVC 4, C# and Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Greeting, everybody.

I am new to ASP .NET MVC and Razor, and I am stuck with a problem: I need the data entered to a form to be available in the same form, after being saved to database, if a certain checkbox is checked. I have found plenty of information about Postback and Crosspage, but none of the articles/tutorials/references details the way to use them. For example, where exactly, in Visual Studio 2012 Express can I see the Page_Load() event?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're reading the wrong kind of tutorial.  You should learn about MVC, not WebForms.  The answer is session or hidden inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC4 is based on the Model View Controller design so the PageLoad() Method isn't really applicable.

For Example what you may be looking for is this

Model

```
public class SampleModel
{
    public int ModelId {get; set;}        
    public string ModelName {get; set;}        
}
```

Controllers

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SampleController()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SampleController(SampleModel model)
{
    //put code here to send to database
    return View(model);
}
```

View

```
@model YourProject.Models.SampleModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModelId)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ModelId)
    <br />
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModelName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ModelName)

   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```